# Kindly increase the gap size in an array (between the \overline and the top line)

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, line-spacing, arrays

Is there a simple way to increase the gap size between the \overline and the top line, in the array? More precisely, here is an example.

An array command

```
$$
\begin{array}{| c | c |}
\cline{1-2}
\overline{a} & \overline{b}    \\
\hline
\end{array}.
$$
```

outputs this.

> How do we make the gap size between the top line and the \overline{b} become even just slightly larger?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use (locally) `\extrarowheight`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{array}{| c | c |}
\hline
\bar{a} & \bar{b} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. Don't use `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503).
2. `\cline` is for rules that aren't supposed to cover an entire row.
3. `\overline` should be `\bar`, when a single character is to be overlined.

Comment: Thank you! This is very informative and educative! Perfect! +1, accepted